# Docker, nginx and several sites on one server

Tags: nginx, docker, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have server with nginx and one working app. I want to add several apps to this servers. I would like to assimilate a few things for myself.

What is the difference between load balancer and reverse proxy?
In which situations should I use the first, and in which situations should I use the second?

What should I use if my sites are static, and what if not static?

And additionally it would be a big plus to hear about containers in the context of several sites for nginx

Comment: As a side node: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy automatic nginx for docker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Differences between load balancer and reverse proxy*

- A reverse proxy accepts a request from a client, forwards it to a server that can fulfill it, and returns the server’s response to the client.
- A load balancer distributes incoming client requests among a group of servers, in each case returning the response from the selected server to the appropriate client.

Taken from [nginx docs](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-vs-load-balancer/)

TL;DR :

**Reverse proxying is about : routing requests to the correct server using the domain name**

**Load balancing is about : distributing load to multiple instances**

*What should I use if my sites are static, and what if not static?*

You can combine an HTTP reverse proxy + load balancing with both static and non static web apps, so it depends.

*And additionally it would be a big plus to hear about containers in the context of several sites for nginx*

I recommend one nginx container per app / site + a dynamic reverse proxy, traefik in particular (http://traefik.io)

Answer (score 0):

You need a **reverse proxy** to route the incoming traffic to the proper application taking into account the content of the original request (and rules that you may define).

When the target application(s) is determined, you will need to **load balance** them in order to distribute the amount of work across them.

Both tasks can be done by software like classic *nginx*, *apache*, *haproxy*, etc or by those that are designed for the microservices world, like *fabio*, *traefik* and others.